# Download large files using ftp protocol

Tags: c#, ftp

i know this is probably not the first time, this is asked.
But i can't find the solution to the problem..

```
  private void bgftpdownload_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpurl + "/" + clientlabel.Text + "/data.7z");
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpuser, ftppass);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
        request.Proxy = null;

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        long fileSize = response.ContentLength;

        request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpurl + "/" + clientlabel.Text + "/data.7z");
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpuser, ftppass);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        using (FtpWebResponse responseFileDownload = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream responseStream = responseFileDownload.GetResponseStream())
        using (FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(LocationFile, FileMode.Create))
        {

            int Length = 2048;
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
            int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
            int bytes = 0;

            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
                bytes += bytesRead;
                int totalSize = (int)(fileSize / 1048576);
                bgftpdownload.ReportProgress((bytes / 1048576) * 100 / totalSize, totalSize);
            }
        }
    }
    private void bgftpdownload_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            progresslabel.Text = e.ProgressPercentage * (int)e.UserState / 100 + " Mb / " + e.UserState + " Mb";
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

I have this code, and its working great.. until its hitting a 2 gb file on the ftp server

I can read on other forums, the value limit for (int) is = 2147483591
So the problem is off cause my byte is getting higher than limit (2147483591)

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Værdien '-45' er ugyldig for 'Value'. 'Value' skal være mellem 'minimum' og 'maximum'.

What can i do to fix this problem?

Comment: use a long (9,223,372,036,854,775,807) or a ulong (18,446,744,073,709,551,615)?

Comment: I have tried "long bytes = 0;" not helping..

Comment: bytesRead also needs to be a long

Comment: As with all questions, "working great until" doesn't really describe what's going wrong. Do you get an exception anywhere? Which one?

Comment: @rmn36 `bytesRead` will never exceed 2048

Comment: rmn36, i also tried that.. but i need to convert "long into int" in the bgftpdownload.ReportProgress section..

Comment: I'm getting this exception:

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Værdien '-45' er ugyldig for 'Value'. 'Value' skal være mellem 'minimum' og 'maximum'. <-- Sorry im using Danish windows..

Comment: The part where you report your progress is `bgftpdownload.ReportProgress((bytes / 1048576) * 100 / totalSize, totalSize);`, and I assume this will be used in the event as `e.ProgressPercentage` part, and the `-45` indicates that an integer overflow has happened. So, the expression which calculates the percentage is overflowing. Can you cast that value explicitly to a longer type, so that it accepts a `long`, in the `.ReportProgess` call?

Comment: I can't get the `ReportProgress` to accept a long in that line..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`long bytes = 0;`
and
`bgftpdownload.ReportProgress((int)(bytes / 1048576) * 100 / totalSize, totalSize);`
Was the solution, i placed the (int) in the ReportProgress the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Your progress bar is triggering the failure, trying to set it to -45 which is invalid.

```
int totalSize = (int)(fileSize / 1048576);
bgftpdownload.ReportProgress((bytes / 1048576) * 100 / totalSize, totalSize);
```

You're getting an overflow on totalSize, which is causing the negative % which is causing the error you're seeing.

... at least I think that's what's wrong.

Comment: As i can see, its `bytes += bytesRead;` thats getting to high a value for int to handle. But how to handle it with long?..

Comment: bytes needs to be a long instead of an int then, a long is basically an int but with more memory so it can store much higher values. I'd also change totalSize to a long, and not cast (fileSize / 1048576) to an int.

Comment: Yes agreed, but `bgftpdownload.ReportProgress((bytes / 1048576) * 100 / totalSize, totalSize);`is failing when using long